# How enricher adapts the service activator and gateway interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, adapter

My question based on official samples: [Spring Integration - Enricher Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/d8e71c687e86e7a7e35d515824832a92df9d4638/basic/enricher)
Let's consider following xml configuration:

```
<int:gateway id="userGateway" default-request-timeout="5000"
                 default-reply-timeout="5000"
                 service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.enricher.service.UserService">
        <int:method name="findUserWithUsernameInMap" request-channel="findUserWithMapEnricherChannel"/>
</int:gateway>
<int:enricher id="findUserWithMapEnricher"
                  input-channel="findUserWithMapEnricherChannel"
                  request-channel="findUserByUsernameServiceChannel"
                  request-payload-expression="payload.username">
        <int:property name="user"    expression="payload"/>
    </int:enricher>

<int:service-activator id="findUserByUsernameServiceActivator"
                           ref="systemService" method="findUserByUsername"
                           input-channel="findUserByUsernameServiceChannel"/>
```

`SystemService` is:

```
public class SystemService {

    public User findUserByUsername(String username) {
            ...    
    }

}
```

`UserService` is:

```
public interface UserService {

    Map<String, Object> findUserWithUsernameInMap(Map<String, Object> userdata);

}
```

So we have 3 components:

**userGateway** <---> **enricher** <---> **findUserByUsernameServiceActivator**

As you can see `UserService#findUserWithUsernameInMap` accepts `Map<String, Object>` but `SystemService#findUserByUsername` accepts the String. So we have to convert Map to string. Looks like:

```
<request-payload-expression="payload.username">
```

is responsible for that.

Moreover `SystemService#findUserByUsername` returns `User` but `UserService#findUserWithUsernameInMap` returns  `Map<String, Object>` but I don't see any place where this tranformation is happen.

So my question is where the `User` -> `Map` transformations is defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration:

```
<int:enricher id="findUserWithMapEnricher"
              input-channel="findUserWithMapEnricherChannel"
              request-channel="findUserByUsernameServiceChannel"
              request-payload-expression="payload.username">
    <int:property name="user"    expression="payload"/>
</int:enricher>
```

Can be explained like:

1. The `findUserWithMapEnricherChannel` brings messages to this component as `Map`.
2. The `request-payload-expression="payload.username"` get a value from the map by `username` key.
3. This plain `username` value is sent to the `findUserByUsernameServiceChannel`
4. The service on that channel returns a `User` result
5. The expression `<int:property name="user"    expression="payload"/>` means: add a new `user` entry into the request `Map` and store there the whole result of service calling on the `findUserByUsernameServiceChannel`

Therefore into the reply in sent an original `Map`, but already with a new `user` entry.
That's the main point of `enricher`: add something new (or modify) in the incoming `payload` and return it back.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice one important thing: `UserService` has the same type for argument and for return type. So we pass some ObjArg to the enricher, then it could optionally extract some data from ObjArg and passes it to the SystemService. When the SystemService returns someResult we enrich ObjArg based on someResult. So we passed map with `username` key and got the map with 2 keys: `username` and `user`

I found answer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher)